# Filling content of cell based on adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a column of data like column B below. The letter "A" denotes software, "B" a service and "C" hardware. How do I match each product with its category to make it look like the table below?

```
   A        B
--------------
Software    A1
Software    A2
Software    A3
Software    A4
Service     B1
Service     B2
Service     B3
Service     B4
Hardware    C1
Hardware    C2
Hardware    C3
Hardware    C4
```

How would I achieve this in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy this formula to `A1` and use AutoFill down.

```
=IF(LEFT(B1,1)="A","Software",IF(LEFT(B1,1)="B","Service",IF(LEFT(B1,1)="C","Hardware","")))
```

The formula consists of 3 formulas nested together.

```
=IF(LEFT(B1,1)="A","Software","")
=IF(LEFT(B1,1)="B","Service","")
=IF(LEFT(B1,1)="C","Hardware","")
```

Comment: nixda, how would I do this if I wanted to do something like a top 10 list. For example, I have a list of names in A, a count of something in columb B. I want to the top 5 names and counts in columns C and D.

Comment: @justingrif Can you please ask this as a new question? I think the solution would be different to this one

Comment: Seems like a limited solution and not easily maintainable. A better solution would be to have a table of products and categories on another sheet, and use VLOOKUP to look up the category and CONCAT to tag on the serial number, but it is unclear from the question how that is assigned - perhaps from an adjacent cell which is manually entered?